# What does the dns_probe_finished_nxdomain error code mean?

Tags: domain-name-system

In Google Chrome, when I visit a website I get the error code `dns_probe_finished_nxdomain`. As is the case with most error messages, this isn't self explanatory. What does this error code mean?

Comment: NXDOMAIN means: domain doesn't exist. I assume that's what Chrome is trying to tell you.

Comment: @joeqwerty I assumed the same. I've also seen `err_name_not_resolved` which is another error message generated by Chrome. It sounds as though it'll be the same but I'm guessing it must mean something different. Do you know if there's a place on the web which documents what these messages mean?

Comment: There aren't that many. `NXDOMAIN` means that a server said authoritatively that the name asked for does not exist. "Did not resolve" means that for some reason the lookup process did not produce a result.

Comment: @henrywright : see https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/error_page/common/net_error_info.h?q=package:%5Echromium$+symbol:dns_probe_finished_nxdomain+exact:yes&l=94 for various error codes, including the one you are specifying, each error code is seen with some comments as explanation. This is obviously specific to chrome/chromium, but other than that NXDOMAIN is a standard DNS error code telling you that the domain requested does not exist (Not eXist DOMAIN)